# How to transfer data from one process to another?

Tags: vhdl

As an example, in the first process I have a binary number that I want to transfer to a second process. How to I do this?

Do i need to use something called a FIFO?

If I need to use a FIFO *must* I use it? Are there any alternatives?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity pwm_control_1 is
port (


--inputs and outputs for clock divider-------------------------------------------------------
            clk_in : in std_logic ;
            clr  : in std_logic;

            pwm_testing: out bit;
            pwm_out: out bit;

            key_0:in bit;
            green_led:out bit





    );
end pwm_control_1;

architecture Behavioral of pwm_control_1 is

signal compare:std_logic_vector( 8 downto 0);
signal q:std_logic_vector (8 downto 0);-- q is for the clock divider ,q can get till 23 
signal q_1:std_logic_vector (23 downto 0);


signal pwm_testing_signal : bit;

signal test             : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
signal step_10_dc   : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
signal step_5_dc        : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
signal duty_cycle_0  : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);

signal duty_cycle_counter  : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);
signal duty_cycle_counter_refresh  : std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);

begin 
test                  <= "000000000";
step_10_dc            <= "000110011";
step_5_dc             <= "000011010";
duty_cycle_counter  <= "000000000";
duty_cycle_counter_refresh <= "000000000";

--



                        key_testing :process (key_0)
            begin 
                    if (key_0='0') then 
                    green_led <='1';
                    duty_cycle_counter <= (duty_cycle_counter+step_5_dc);-- counter for adding the limit of the PWM 
                    else
                   green_led <='0';
                  end if;

        end process key_testing;

    `               duty_cycle_counter_refresh <=duty_cycle_counter;

        add_5_or_10_duty_cycle :process(clk_in,clr,q ,key_0)

        begin 

        if (clk_in'event and clk_in='1') then -- starting the q counter 
        q<= q+1; --first I torn on the counter q that is used for clock driver then 

                                        if (q<=(duty_cycle_counter_refresh )) then pwm_testing_signal <='1'; 
                                        else 
                                        pwm_testing_signal <='0';
                                        end if ;


            end if;
        end process add_5_or_10_duty_cycle;

                                                pwm_testing <=pwm_testing_signal;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Could you please provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? So please give us a testbench, so it's easier to reproduce

Comment: When I teach VHDL, I teach two things: (i) the language and (ii) what HW you get when you synthesise it. As far as (ii) is concerned, a VHDL signal ends up as a piece of metal - a track, a wire etc. As far as (i) is concerned, a VHDL signal is the language construct which enables VHDL processes to communicate with each other. That's your answer: drive a signal in one process; read it in another.